# Why do we say "he asked after you" not "he asked about you"?

Tags: grammar, etymology

What are the origins of "ask after" and is it dying out as the way we currently speak?

Comment: We do say both. But, simply, *after* here implies showing some concern for the object of the inquiry, while *about* may do the same or simply be a request for information. The former implies that the person knows you and has some interest in your well being; *about* may be more dispassionate.

Answer (score 2):

Oxford Advanced Learner's dictionary says that this is a phrasal verb which implies being interested in "how somebody is, what they are doing, etc.", i.e. it's not necessarily about health or well-being, but trying to sound in a general way more personal and more caring, a step closer to the people you mention.

Here is the link: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ask-after?q=ask+after

It seems to me that saying 'ask about' is slightly less personal that 'ask after'. Such differences must exist due to nuances in meanings.

Answer (score 0):

It is more common today to ask *for* someone than to ask *after* them, but it means the same thing.  It means to inquire or make inquiries regarding that person.  The OED says you will still encounter *ask after someone* in dialect use, but it has for the most part been replaced by asking *for* someone.

Here are its last two citations for that sense:

> - 1866 G. Macdonald *Ann. Q. Neighb.* xxx. (1878) 524 – To ask after their health when he met them.
> - *Mod*. — Did any one ask for me, while I was out? When you reach that point, ask again.

Asking *about* someone isn’t necessarily asking *for* them, however.

Comment: It doesn't mean exactly the same thing. From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ask?q=ask+after#ask__13): "**ask after** or *Scottish* **for** *(British)* enquire about the health or well-being of". The phrase **ask about** *can* mean asking about somebody's health, but it could also mean other things, like prying into their affairs.

Comment: I've looked at the OED's entry now, and I see why you answered as you did; I think the OED is too comprehensive to easily deduce the actual current British meaning from.

Comment: I meet with 'asked after you' more than 'asked about you', but it's not what the police do.